Is it true that simple future cannot be used in clauses beginning with time expressions?
I am learning from this website englishpage.com and I have encountered this:

No Future in Time Clauses
Like all future forms, the simple future
cannot be used in clauses beginning with time expressions such as
when, while, before, after, by the time, as soon as, if, unless, etc.
Instead of simple future, simple present is used.
Examples:

When you will arrive tonight, we will go out for dinner. Not Correct
When you arrive tonight, we will go out for dinner. Correct


Is the above true?
If "yes" then also it is not correct to say for example "Before you will arrive tonight, we will start the show." but the correct version will be "Before you arrive tonight, we will start the show."
What about this form:
When will you arrive tonight? <= Is it correct?

I was taught this rule too. To be more precise, the website you are referring to should refer to temporal conjunctions in subordinate clauses instead of "time expressions"  in general. "When will you arrive tonight?" is a direct question and a main clause and therefore correct in my opinion. Disclaimer: not a native speaker of English.

The website is perfectly correct. We don't use will in a time clause making a statement about the future, but we do use it when asking a question - so When will you arrive? is correct.

@Saleh Rezq You should also notice that in object clauses you are free to use future tenses. "I'd like to know when you will return (will have finished your work, will be getting home)!", "I would like to inquire if you will give us your oppinion as to the merits of Italian cuisine" and so on.

There are plenty of other websites that agree with this, e.g. University of Victoria, British Council. But you already have a website saying not to do it, so that makes me ask, why are you asking here? Why don't you believe what your link says? What evidence would you like? Is there something you're not telling us? I could post more links but if you don't like yours, why would you like mine?

@StuartF Doubts because other tenses can use time expressions with the past tenses and present tense, I just wanted a human response to satisfy my doubts. It is ok and thank you for the links.



When you will arrive tonight, we will go out for dinner. (x)




When you arrive tonight, we will go out for dinner. (o)




When will you arrive tonight? (o)


Time adverbial clause abhors future tense. The no.3 is not an adverbial clause but a main clause. Main clause means one real subject and one real verb are included in a sentence.
Also, conditional adverbial clause (starting with "if") loathes future tense.
If you will want to come tonight, please join us. (x)
If you want to come tonight, please join us. (o)
